# Webmatrix how to add a class if input type text box is not empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I want to add a class if input type text box is not empty or null. I'm trying to do something like this.

**.cshtml**

```
@{
    var value= string.IsNullOrEmpty;
}

<form action="">
    <input type="text" value="@value" class="@(value=!null ? "thisclass" : "")">
</form>
```

I'm sorry for this bad example but I really don't know how to explain it and I'm not using MVC or Database, this is a simple Input `type="text"` box. Please Help!

Comment: If you change `value` to `string.Empty` instead, and the comparison to `@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "thisclass" : "")`, I think it will work better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started a new MVC-project.

This is the code I use in Index.cshtml and it works fine. (I get a red background in the text field)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

    var value = string.Empty;
}

<style type="text/css">
    .testclass {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <input type="text" class="@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "testclass" : "")" />
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I only want to add the class if someone write something in the input text box but it's already red.

Comment: Ah, then just flip the comparison to `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, so that it only adds the class when it is not empty.

Comment: If you want it to add the class as you write, you should look into javascript. There's an event called `onkeyup`, where you could check if the textbox contains any text, and then you could add/remove the class as you see fit. For MVC to work, you have to set the value before the page is rendered.

Comment: I think the value tag is required to do this. `<input type="text" value="@???"` ...

Answer (score 0):

As stated by NoLifeKing, this is the server side solution to test if the input is empty and change its class accordingly:

```
<input type="text" id="testinput" value="@value" 
   class="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "thisclass" : "")"  />
```

If you want that the input class changes as you write, you must use jquery, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testinput').keyup(function () {
        if (!this.value) {
            $(this).addClass('thisclass');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('thisclass');
        }
    });
});
```